# One efficient SQL call instead of 500

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, loops, controller, refactoring

In my view, I've got a fiddly loop which creates 500 SQL queries (to get the info for 500 books). How can I avoid lots of SQL queries by loading a variable up in the controller?

My current (pseudo) code:

controller index action:

```
@books = Book.scoped.where(:client_id => @client.id).text_search(params[:query])
@feature_root = Book.multiple_summary_details_by_category( @books ) 
  #...returns a hash of books
@features = @feature_root.to_a.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
```

index.html.haml

```
    = render :partial => "feature", :locals => { :features => @features }
```

_features.html.haml

```
  - features.each_with_index do |(cat_name, array_of_books), i|  
    %h2
      = cat_name
    - array_of_books[0..10].each do |feature|
      = link_to image_tag(feature[:cover], :class => "product_image_tiny"), book_path(feature[:book])
    # more code
    - array_of_books.sort_by{ |k, v| k["Author"] }.each do |feature|
      - feature.each do |heading,value|
        %span.summary_title
          = heading + ':'
        %span.summary_value
          = value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far? It should be quite easy with standard ActiveRecord queries as documented in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html.

Also, instead of

```
array_of_books.sort_by{ |k, v| k["Author"] }
```

try something like

```
Book.order("author DESC")
```

(not sure about your exact model here) to let the db do the sorting rather than putting them in an array and let ruby handle it.

Comment: Sure, I can use normal queries in the controller to get the main collection but it's iterating through that collection which is generating lots of queries. My question is really how to minimise the number of queries called from the view layer. If I put a loop in the controller, each iteration overwrites the previous one, so I can't use it in the view.

Comment: I don't really understand your model, but you could just create a collection/array in the controller that contains all the data you need (summary_title and summary_value I suppose) which should be possible with one query.